# Repeating a sequence of lines in Java

Tags: java, repeat

I can't think how to word what I want to do, but hopefully this will explain.

My friend is making a text-based adventure game, and I was working on separating a part of the game out for ease of management.

In the game, the stats of the player, the player inventory and many more get sent to another class.

```
    static Char player;
    static battle bat;

    public static void directchoice(Char p, battle b) {
    player = p;
    bat = b;
    String[] rightLeft = {"Left", "Right"};
    int direct = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Left or Right?", "Option", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, rightLeft, rightLeft[0]);
    if(direct == 0){
        Maze.makeChoice(player, bat);
    }
    if(direct == 1){
        Maze.DoorChoice(player, bat);   
    }
}
```

As can be seen here, at the beginning of the class, "player" and "bat" are a Character and a Battle. These are imported from the previous section of the game.

The "Char p, battle b" seen in the subroutine brackets, along with the "player = p; bat = b;" inside the sub have to be repeated for every subroutine.

So for example, here is another subroutine within that class:

```
    public static void DoorChoice(Char p, battle b) {   
    player = p;
    bat = b;
    String[] others = {"Go through door", "Don't go through"};
int checkers = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Go through door or not?", "Option", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, others, others[0]);
```

There are a bunch of others, such as player inventory, monster, and more that also need to be repeated. What I'm trying to do is create a way of repeating those lines of code automatically for each subroutine, as opposed to having to either type them all out or copy and paste.

I tried what I could think of, but being still relatively noobish to java, I don't know what to do to repeat those lines.

I hope this makes sense, and I'm sorry if it doesn't :(

Comment: use loop if you want to repeat anything.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called `loop`. There is [many types of loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm).

Here is a generic example of a `for-loop`:

```
for (int counter; counter<repeatXTimes;counter++){
//This will repeat for as long as counter<repeatXTimes, and counter will increase once per loop.
}
```

Comment: But would this work to automate declaration of those things within the sub? I know about using for loops but can't think how they'd apply to this type of problem

Comment: I've re-read your post and it seems what you are trying to do is not have have it repeat the same code but not have to pass the same thing as a parameter over and over. If thats the case, then declare player and bat as member variables of whatever class they are in and your problem will be solved. Maybe even possibly include them in the constructor for the class.